# Put powershell code into function, script or cmdletbinding

Tags: powershell

If I put this code below (to check a certain gpo setting) into the console of Powershell, the output is shown correctly. If I want to make a function, script or cmdletbinding of it, it only shows me the output of $policydetails.

#Get the GPO Guid

```
[xml]$GpoXml = Get-GPOReport -Guid (Get-GPO $GPOName).Id -ReportType xml
```

#Create a custom object containing only the policy "fields" we're interested in

```
$PolicyDetails = foreach ($p in $GpoXml.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension.Policy) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Name" = $p.Name
        "State" = $p.State
        "Filter" = $p.EditText.Value
    }
}
$SvcPolicyDetails = foreach ($p in $GpoXml.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension.NTServices.NTService.Properties) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Service" = $p.ServiceName
        "Action" = $p.ServiceAction
        "Start" = $p.StartupType
    }
}
$PolicySecurity = foreach ($p in $GpoXml.GPO.SecurityDescriptor.Permissions.TrusteePermissions.Trustee.Name) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "SecurityFiltering" = $p.'#text'
    }
}
$PolicyLinks = foreach ($p in $GpoXml.GPO.LinksTo) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "OU-Link" = $p.SOMPath
        "Enabled" = $p.Enabled
    }
}
```

#Let's see the results

```
$PolicyDetails
$SvcPolicyDetails
$PolicySecurity
$PolicyLinks
```

I tried several things...

1.Function:

```
Function Get-GpoDetails {
  <script code>
}
```

2.Cmdletbinding:

```
Function Get-GpoDetails { 
  param (
     [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
     [string]$GPONameWinRm )

  <script code> ### without variable $GPONameWinRm
}
```

3.Script:

```
Copy <script code> into .ps1
```

None of these things worked. They all give the same output, only the output of the variable '$policydetails' is shown.

How can I make this work in a function or script or cmdletbinding so that not all the code needs to be put into the console for the right output?

Comment: Please post your code as plain text, not screenshots :)

Comment: Did you start PS As Admin?  PS will not run in admin unless you right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: I figured out a way...
Under #see the results I made
$PolicySummary = $PolicyDetails,$SvcPolicyDetails,$PolicySecurity,$PolicyLinks
$PolicySummary.name
$PolicySummary.state
$PolicySummary.filter
$PolicySummary.service
$PolicySummary.action
$PolicySummary.start
$PolicySummary.securityfiltering
$PolicySummary.ou-link
$PolicySummary.enabled

If I put this at the end ot the other code and put it in a cmdletbinding, it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is because you output 3 different object "types" in a single list. Powershell knows that they're all `[PSCustomObject]`, so it wraps them together

Powershell displays results using properties from the first object by default:

```bash
$result = Get-GpoDetails

$result  ## outputs like

Name                                        State   Filter
----                                        -----   ------
Configure wireless policy processing        Enabled
Specify startup policy processing wait time Enabled

## missing other output... ##
```

All the data does still get returned. Try formatting the output or manually specifying fields to display it:

```bash
$result | Format-List
$result | ConvertTo-Json

# example of adding fields that Format-Table would ignore
$result | select Name,State,SecurityFiltering,OULink,Enabled | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code like this and get the wanted results in nice output format

```
Function Get-GpoWinRM
{
[CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$GPOName
    )
```

#Get the GPO Guid

```
[xml]$GpoXml = Get-GPOReport -Guid (Get-GPO $GPOName).Id -ReportType xml
```

#Create a custom object containing only the policy "fields" we're interested in

```
$PolicyDetails = foreach ($p in $GpoXml.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension.Policy) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Name" = $p.Name
        "State" = $p.State
        "Filter" = $p.EditText.Value
    }
}
$SvcPolicyDetails = foreach ($p in $GpoXml.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension.NTServices.NTService.Properties) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Service" = $p.ServiceName
        "Action" = $p.ServiceAction
        "Start" = $p.StartupType
    }
}
$PolicySecurity = foreach ($p in $GpoXml.GPO.SecurityDescriptor.Permissions.TrusteePermissions.Trustee.Name) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "SecurityFiltering" = $p.'#text'
    }
}
$PolicyLinks = foreach ($p in $GpoXml.GPO.LinksTo) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "OU-Link" = $p.SOMPath
        "Enabled" = $p.Enabled
    }
}
```

#Let's see the results

```
$PolicySummary = $PolicyDetails,$SvcPolicyDetails,$PolicySecurity,$PolicyLinks
Write-Host -ForeGroundColor Green "*** WINRM POLICY ***"
Write-Host -ForeGroundColor Cyan "PolicySetting and Status:"
$PolicySummary.name
$PolicySummary.state
Write-Host -ForeGroundColor Cyan "Allowed IP-range to WinRM:"
$PolicySummary.filter
Write-Host -ForeGroundColor Cyan "PolicySetting Service:"
$PolicySummary.service
$PolicySummary.action
$PolicySummary.start
Write-Host -ForeGroundColor Cyan "SecurityFiltering:"
$PolicySummary.securityfiltering
Write-Host -ForeGroundColor Cyan "OU Link:"
$PolicySummary.'ou-link'
$PolicySummary.enabled
}
```

All the previous code results in this output:

```
*** WINRM POLICY ***
PolicySetting and Status:
Allow remote server management through WinRM
Enabled
Allowed IP-range to WinRM:
172.16.0.0-172.16.0.254, 172.16.1.0-172.16.1.254
*
PolicySetting Service:
WinRM
START
AUTODELAYED
SecurityFiltering:
DH\Enterprise Admins
DH\Domain Admins
NT AUTHORITY\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
OU Link:
DH.herhaling.loc/HO-DIGITAL3/Machines
true
```